# Web-console Exception: No broker is found at any of the 1 configured urls

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms

I'm trying to start the web-console in tomee+ 1.5.0, like it is shown here:
http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html (Example configuration using Tomcat)

I use the following parameter when starting the server:

*-Dcatalina.base="D:\Kit\apache-tomee-plus-1.5.0" -Dcatalina.home="D:\Kit\apache-tomee-plus-1.5.0" -Dwtp.deploy="D:\Kit\apache-tomee-plus-1.5.0\wtpwebapps" -Djava.endorsed.dirs="D:\Kit\apache-tomee-plus-1.5.0\endorsed" -Dwebconsole.type=properties -Dwebconsole.jms.url=tcp://localhost:61616 -Dwebconsole.jmx.url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi -Dwebconsole.jmx.user=tomee -Dwebconsole.jmx.password=tomee -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099*

I can connect with jconsole to `service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/jmxrmi` but I don't see the "org.apache.activemq" in MBeans. When I try to access the web-console at

> `http://localhost:8080/activemq-web-console-5.7.0/`

I keep getting the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No broker is found at any of the 1 configured urls
at org.apache.activemq.web.RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.createConnection(RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.java:168)
```

This is the broker in the activemq.xml file of the web-console war:

```
<broker brokerName="web-console" useJmx="true" xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core">

<persistenceAdapter>
  <kahaDB directory="${activemq.data}/kahadb"/>
</persistenceAdapter>

<transportConnectors>
  <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://localhost:61616"/>
  <transportConnector name="stomp" uri="stomp://localhost:61613"/>
</transportConnectors> </broker>
```

Can someone give me a hint regarding this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is related to the "Datasource" parameter from ActiveMQResourceAdapter. This version works:

```
    <Resource id="JMSAdapter" type="ActiveMQResourceAdapter">
            BrokerXmlConfig = broker:(tcp://localhost:61616)?persistent=false&useJmx=true
            ServerUrl = tcp://localhost:61616
            Datasource =
    </Resource>
```

This is related to the following: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TOMEE-474